# Implode a css image in php

Tags: php, drupal-7

Can anyone how to implode a image file in breadcrumb in php.

this is my code

```
function fold_breadcrumb($variables) {
  $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];
  if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
// Use CSS to hide titile .element-invisible.
   $output = '<h2 class="element-invisible">' . t('You are here') . '</h2>';
// comment below line to hide current page to breadcrumb
$breadcrumb[] = drupal_get_title();
   $count=  sizeof($breadcrumb);
 /* print $count; */
  $primarytitle=$breadcrumb[$count-2];
 /* print $test; */
  $output .= '<nav class="breadcrumb">' . implode(' » ', $breadcrumb) . '</nav>';
  return $output;
 }
}
```

Here i need to implode a css image file instead of **»**

Comment: What do you mean with "implode a css image"?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this maybe?

`$img_breadcrumb = '<img src="/path/img_bcrumb.png">';`

then

```
$output .= '<nav class="breadcrumb">' . implode($img_breadcrumb, $breadcrumb) . '</nav>';
```

Answer (score 0):

What about simple analogy:

```
implode(' <img src="path/to/yourimage.file" /> ', $breadcrumb)
```

Or better:

```
implode(' <span class="separator"></span> ', $breadcrumb)
```

and define CSS background to your `.separator` class.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple:

```
implode('<span class="separator"><img src="path/to/imagefile.ext" alt="yourimage.file"/></span>', $breadcrumb);
```

Hope this helps :)